# How to create a custom trigger in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager say you have three different *items*:

```
If variable = 2

If URL = abc.com

If URL = def.com
```

Is there a way to create a single trigger that will mean `A AND (B OR C)`?

I know I can create `A` & `B` in a single trigger and `A` & `C` in a single trigger, or the same groupings in a trigger group. Is there a way to create this without creating multiple triggers?

Comment: What do you mean by `trigger` in the context of Google Analytics? `triggers` don't exist in GA (but they do in Google Tag Manager).

Comment: There are no triggers in GA. I somewhat suspect you are talking about filters or segments, in which case you can set "match regex" as matching condition for your second condition and use "B|C" (the pipe being the "or" operator).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. A trigger responds to an event, so you first have to select the trigger type. Then you add filters so the trigger only activates when certain conditions are met.

All filter conditions in the trigger need to be met to activate the trigger. But your example does not have three different items, it has two different items and one of the items can take two different values. So this becomes a matter of selecting the appropriate match types.

The first variable has one value that is supposed to activate the trigger, so the match type is "equals".

The second variable has two possible values that are supposed to activate the trigger. For this, you can use a regular expression that checks if the variable has either one or the other value. The "or" operator in regular expressions is the pipe character "|". If you want to make sure that this matches only exact strings, you can add the "starts with" character "^" and the "end with" character "$" to the start and end of the respective strings.

This will look something like this example:

[image: Trigger configuration]